# Integer types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value '0x0')

Tags: android, eclipse, reverse-engineering

I had built an android application using eclipse.I recently got the project deleted by mistake.But i had the apk file for the project.So i used apktool,dex2jar and java debugger to obtain the source code for my application, but now when i imported the application in eclipse and tried to run it, i get these errors :

```
[2012-12-24 20:30:54 - loser] W/ResourceType( 2328): Bad XML block: header size 78 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-12-24 20:30:54 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\values-v14\styles.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-12-24 20:30:54 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\menu\main.xml:4: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value '0x0').
[2012-12-24 20:35:54 - loser] W/ResourceType( 3520): Bad XML block: header size 100 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-12-24 20:35:54 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\values-v14\styles.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-12-24 20:35:54 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\menu\main.xml:4: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value '0x0').
[2012-12-24 20:43:13 - loser] W/ResourceType( 2376): Bad XML block: header size 100 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-12-24 20:43:13 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\values-v14\styles.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-12-24 20:43:13 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\menu\main.xml:4: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value '0x0').
[2012-12-24 20:45:55 - loser] W/ResourceType( 3740): Bad XML block: header size 78 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2012-12-24 20:45:55 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\values-v14\styles.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-12-24 20:45:55 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\menu\main.xml:4: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value '0x0').
[2012-12-24 20:50:49 - loser] W/ResourceType( 3916): Bad XML block: header size 94 or total size 7002568 is larger than data size 0
[2012-12-24 20:50:49 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\values-v14\styles.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-12-24 20:50:49 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\menu\main.xml:4: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value '0x0').
[2012-12-24 20:50:56 - loser] W/ResourceType( 2780): Bad XML block: header size 96 or total size 7129120 is larger than data size 0
[2012-12-24 20:50:56 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\values-v14\styles.xml:1: error: Error parsing XML: no element found
[2012-12-24 20:50:56 - loser] C:\Users\itz_n_000\workspace\loser\res\menu\main.xml:4: error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'showAsAction' with value '0x0').
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use following mapping:

```
    <!-- How this item should display in the Action Bar, if present. -->
    <attr name="showAsAction">
        <!-- Never show this item in an action bar, show it in the overflow menu instead.
             Mutually exclusive with "ifRoom" and "always". -->
        <flag name="never" value="0" />
        <!-- Show this item in an action bar if there is room for it as determined
             by the system. Favor this option over "always" where possible.
             Mutually exclusive with "never" and "always". -->
        <flag name="ifRoom" value="1" />
        <!-- Always show this item in an actionbar, even if it would override
             the system's limits of how much stuff to put there. This may make
             your action bar look bad on some screens. In most cases you should
             use "ifRoom" instead. Mutually exclusive with "ifRoom" and "never". -->
        <flag name="always" value="2" />
        <!-- When this item is shown as an action in the action bar, show a text
             label with it even if it has an icon representation. -->
        <flag name="withText" value="4" />
        <!-- This item's action view collapses to a normal menu
             item. When expanded, the action view takes over a
             larger segment of its container. -->
        <flag name="collapseActionView" value="8" />
    </attr>
```